# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message in parse sdk

Tags: php, sdk, parse-platform

I have used the following code for get db data:

```
require 'autoload.php';
$app_id='AAAAA';
$rest_key='XXXXX';
$master_key='RRRRR';

use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
$object = new ParseQuery("Schools");
$playername = $object->get("playername");
```

I am having a "Schools"class in my parse account db with some data. I am try to get the "playername" value but I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in C:\xampp\htdocs\planlet\src\Parse\ParseClient.php:250 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\planlet\src\Parse\ParseQuery.php(305): Parse\ParseClient::_request('GET', '/1/classes/Scho...', NULL, NULL, false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\planlet\src\Parse\ParseQuery.php(248): Parse\ParseQuery->find(false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\planlet\src\Parse\ParseQuery.php(70): Parse\ParseQuery->first(false) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\planlet\first.php(23): Parse\ParseQuery->get('schoolName') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\planlet\src\Parse\ParseClient.php on line 250
```

now i am working on my localhost xampp server  XAMPP 1.8.2 [PHP: 5.4.31]

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a patch provided by Atif Ghaffar in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/f5RPj6DHA2E group to work with Parse SDK in XAMPP environment.

You can fix the issue by replacing your ParseClient.php file with this https://gist.githubusercontent.com/allinora/df4dde146bdc4d635306/raw/67a4c2a560e3f69c3d4e4f51b00e5711dc94b520/ParseClient.php

Answer (score 2):

I was Getting the same issue. 
you need to tell curl not verify ssl peer in parse library.
To do this 
go to Parse/ParseClient.php

open this file, you will find

```
 $rest = curl_init();
```

after this line add the following code

```
curl_setopt($rest, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

this will solve your problem